# How does a pulsed laser diode driver circuit work

Tags: laser

So i am looking at pulsed laser diodes, and i want to build a circuit for it to work. https://www.osram-os.com/Graphics/XPic7/00054198_0.pdf/Standard%20Pulsed%20Laser%20Diode.pdf
This is the article im using for my diode. I understand that the laser stores its electrical pulses in the capacitor but thats all i understand, maybe you guys can point me in a better direction of how the pulsed laser diode works and what it needs to drive. Also does the laser actually pulse or is it continuous wave with pulses of evergy in it?

Comment: Laser diodes are CW devices, they have a laser threshold current which once exceeded results in a continuous optical wave output. Pulsed lasers are simply laser diodes used where pulses are generated externally to turn the Laser diode on/off rapidly ...hence 'pulsed'.

Comment: @JackCreasey, First generations of new laser diode designs tend to not be "CW" in the sense that they'll burn themselves up if operated CW. Making a CW laser diode requires getting the design efficient enough (and heatsinking well enough) to avoid this. While an integraged laser diode doesn't contain any mechanism for self-pulsation, it's also possible to make an external cavity diode laser that does. (note "diode laser" rather than "laser diode").

Comment: The key to this question is more about understanding the operation of the avalanche transistor than understanding the laser diode.

Comment: @ThePhoton. The laser diode IS definitely CW (look at the datasheet). it has no other operating mode.  You are saying you can't operate it continuously (which is different to CW) ...I agree with that. But the if the laser outputs a single frequency/wave length continuously for the length of a pulse on time..... It's still CW light.

Comment: So the avalanche transistor is what i need to look at for sure. So is the diode cw with pulses in energy or is it actually pulsed like light for 10ns no light for 10ns ect ect

Comment: @JackCreasey, in my experience in the area of laser diodes it's very common to use "CW" to distinguish from "pulsed" laser, indicating their capability to be operated a particular way, not to indicate inherent pulsing or non-pulsing behavior. After all, the laser diode is only a gain medium. It doesn't become a diode laser until you add a pump source (which can be pulsed or continuous).

Comment: Also, OP hasn't specified a part number, so I'm not sure what datasheet to look at. I promise you the plastic package shown in the linked app note won't carry 70 A in CW operation.

Comment: I didnt specify because i dont know what i want either, i am looking at the plastic package but i just want to understand the circuit, what you need and how it works.

Comment: so the avalanche transistor allows you to have very high switching speeds correct?

Comment: what is the difference between the plastic pulsed laser diodes and a cw laser diode if they both can be pulsed with a driver board?